# Advanced Custom Field User Help URL

Tags: plugins, metabox, post-thumbnails, advanced-custom-fields

Hi I'm using ACF or Advanced Custom Fields which i saw here a while ago..

What i want is to output a second featured image in the homepage..

Question: 1

```
<div class="jpl-widgets-d" style="background: url('<?php the_field('featured_home_page_image'); ?>') no-repeat;">
</div>
```

`<?php the_field('featured_home_page_image'); ?>` = URL OF THE IMAGE
The ACF should output the URL of the image i uploaded..

Here's the plugin documentation [LINK](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/image/)

Field Name: featured_home_page_image
Field type: Image
Return Value: URL

Help. thanks!

Comment: Have you already checked their support forums? If so: Please add a link on both ends.

Comment: Not yet, i thought posting here would be faster...

Comment: Give it try there as well. And add a link, maybe that helps solving it faster as reputation comes into the game.

Comment: Ok, Unfortunately im working locally..  If they need more code i'll give it ..

Comment: You are showing us the code, but not the result. What is in the `src` attribute or the `style` attribute after you run the code. Look at the page source. Never write "it's not working" in a question. Tell what is happening or not happening.

Comment: Edited the question,,

Comment: There are many `img` tags on the page source. Which one is the result of your code above? Or are you using the background image?

Comment: yes im using the background-image , the link above is the plugin documentation...

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact thing working on a current project.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="photo-feature" style="background: url(<?php the_field('the-image', $page->ID) ;?>) no-repeat center center; "></div>
```

Keep in mind a couple of things:

1. You may need to use $post->ID or $page->ID if you're using a custom query.
2. Make sure you're not overriding your background CSS anywhere else (use inspector to double check)

Finally - you should take the single quotes out of your inline CSS.

`style: url(path)` not `style: url('path')`

Comment: I'm trying to output it in my static front page ...  i followed your code , still no luck. <div class="jpl-widgets-d" style="background-image: url(<?php the_field('featuredimg_url', $page->ID); ?>) no-repeat;">

Comment: i changed the field name into 'featuredimg_url'

Comment: the image is coming from a different page .. and show it on my homepage ..

Comment: Are you getting other page content from that page?  Can you edit your question and include your custom query?